# How to write date and time in footer

Tags: header-footer, datetime

I am writing a report in which i need to write date and time in the footer. How do I write date and time in footer?

like

```
      Jan 8, 2013 5:45 PM
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, I'm glad it was helpful. Looking at your profile, I see that you have asked 31 questions, but you have never cast a single up-vote. Up-voting is the currency of the site, and you should try to up-vote any answers that you find helpful- please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask for further information.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [`fancyhdr`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fancyhdr) and [`datetime`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/datetime) package to help with this, as demonstrated in the following MWE.

Note that `\today` is actually defined in `LaTeX` (no extra packages needed), but you need `datetime` for `\currenttime`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{datetime}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\today\ \currenttime}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This generates the following footer.

[image: screenshot of generated PDF]

The `fancyhf` command clears the `header` and the `footer`, and the `fancyfoot` command does the specific part of your question. Setting the `pagestyle` as `fancy` seals the deal.

Comment: Note: datetime is considered obsolete and replaced with datetime2.

Comment: This put a horizontal rule in my header, so I added \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt} to remove it.